# batch file to convert xml to cpp

Tags: xml, batch-file

in process of making a tool to convert xml file to a cpp map, I write this below batch file. The xml files mainly contain {key,value} and the tool is to convert those {key,value} into a map in cpp, but it does not work, please refer my actual output and expected output, please help me for the wrong codes ?

```
@ECHO off
title Convert_Tool_v1.0

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::create output folder
@RD /S /Q "output"
md "output"

::build "array" of folders to access each of them
set folderCnt=0
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad *') do (
    set /a folderCnt+=1
    set "folder!folderCnt!=%%F"
)

::make cpp file for each values_XXX/strings.xml
for /l %%N in (1 1 %folderCnt%) do (
    ::echo %%N - !folder%%N!
    call :MAKE_CPP_FILE !folder%%N!
)

del ".\output\output.cpp" /s /f /q
echo convert finished

::function to make cpp files
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
:MAKE_CPP_FILE
    ::echo current folder is: %~1

    ::create file
    echo.>".\output\%~1.cpp"

    ::check each line of xml file, convert line and write to output files
    @echo off
    set "replace_from_1= \<\/string\>="
    set "replace_to_1=\"},"

    set "replace_from_2= \<string name\="
    set "replace_to_2={"

    set "replace_from_3= \"\>"
    set "replace_to_3=\",\""

    set "source=%~1\\strings.xml"
    set "target=.\output\%~1.cpp"

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    (
       for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
            set "line=%%b"
            if defined line set "line=!line:%replace_from_1%=%replace_to_1%!"
            ::if line doesnt contain key, then don't convert this line
            if errorlevel 1 (
                set "line="
            )
            ::continue convert key,value
            if defined line set "line=!line:%replace_from_2%=%replace_to_2%!"
            if defined line set "line=!line:%replace_from_3%=%replace_to_2%!"
            echo(!line!
       )
    ) > %target%
    endlocal

EXIT /B 0
```

the content of xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <!-- Version : BDG14625.003.09.15-->
  <!--C1 Strings-->
  <!-- Start 20180409: Added font names as strings to handle font issues, as a suggested solution -->
  <string name="font_name_Regular">GMSansUI_Regular</string> 
  <string name="font_name_Medium">GMSansUI_Medium</string> 
  <string name="font_name_Light">GMSansUI_Light</string>
  <!-- End 20180409: Added font names as strings to handle font issues, as a suggested solution -->
  <string name="audio_accessory_audio_short_ipc">Accessory Audio</string>
  <string name="audio_action_unavailable_short_ipc">Action unavailable.</string>
  <string name="audio_action_unavailable_while_indexing_short_ipc">Action unavailable while indexing.</string>
...
```

expected output map cpp is likely:

```
{"font_name_Regular","GMSansUI_Regular"},   
{"font_name_Medium","GMSansUI_Medium"},     
{"font_name_Light","GMSansUI_Light"},   
{"audio_accessory_audio_short_ipc","Accessory Audio"},  
{"audio_action_unavailable_short_ipc","Action unavailable."},   
...
```

actual output is:

```
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
line:={
```

thank you so much !!

Comment: __"It does not work"__ is a very bad example of a problem description, but nevertheless... You honestly chose the worst tool to do this. Why not consider something like perl? Perl has xml parser modules that actual maintains the format of the xml. You are basically trying to access a file with specific tag locations and it is going to go wrong, very soon.

Comment: I'm not sure whether and how debugging can be made in batch files. (`bash` has a nice debug mode which helped me to make more complex script files running.) However, even in batch files you could use [print-debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Techniques) i.e. `echo` variables to find out where your code is broken.

Comment: Batch file is not very suitable for xml parsing. Consider Powershell or VBScript instead.

Comment: There are many options for doing things like this, XSLT, python, perl even c++. I wouldn't recommend writing anything much more complex than executing a few commands as a batch script.